# Android OJDBC phantom exception

Tags: android, exception, ojdbc

I'm trying to connect my android application to my oracle 10g DB, i'm using JDK 1.6, OJDBC14.jar and working on a 4.+ application. I used to have a few problem with the driver but here comes the best one : after excecuting this code :

```
String url="jdbc:oracle:thin:usr/pwd@r2d2.iut-orsay.u-psud.fr:1521:etudom";
Connection co = null;

try {
    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
    popUp("Driver Ok");
}
// Should never happend
catch (ClassNotFoundException e){
    popUp("ERROR: Driver's missing");
    //System.exit(1);
}
// Unknow problem
catch (Exception e){
    popUp("ERROR : " + e.getMessage() + "\nFrom: " + e.getCause());
}


try {
    co = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
    popUp("Connection ok");
}
// In case of internet problem
catch (SQLException e) {
    popUp("Throw from SQLException\nERROR : " + e.getMessage());
    //System.exit(1);
}
// unknown problem
catch (Exception e){
    popUp("ERROR from getConnection :\nMessage: " + e.getMessage() + "\nFrom: " + e.getCause() + "\nMessage extra: "+e.getLocalizedMessage());
}
```

And I've got a popUp like that :

> ERROR from getConnection :
>   Message: null
>   From: null
>   Message extra: null

No output in the log or in the console.

I'm literaly *lost*

Any help would be great!

Ps: sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Are you trying to connect directly to the Oracle database from the mobile device or emulator?

Comment: Yes, i've tried from the emulator and from a mobile device, I would add that my computer is able to reach the ODB without trouble.

Comment: That is is the problem right there; you cannot directly connect to a database of any kind, except for the the built-in SQLite DB from the device. To get pass your problem you need to create a service layer that will access the DB via an API for your app and not try to connect to it from the device, it's not going to work like that.

Comment: I'm new to all theses java stuff, can you explain a little more what you're saying and why i'm able to reach the DB in a no-android java projet and not in this one? Thanks

Comment: Remember to accept if my answer helped.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you are not able to connect the device to your Oracle DB is, mobile devices are not equipped to carry out such actions as they are not built with drivers for the vast amount of Databases that are out there. However, in order to connect your app to the Oracle DB you have to create what is called a **`Web Service`** or an **`API`** to get the job done. Check out these tutorials they should get you rolling:

- [How to connect Android with PHP, MySQL](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/) (the concept here is the same, just use your Oracle DB instead)
- [Oracle Mobile Database server](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/products/database-mobile-server/overview/index.html?origref=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8894665/what-is-the-best-way-to-connect-between-android-and-oracle-database)
- [Android to Oracle connectivity through java](http://androracle.blogspot.in/2012/07/java-class-as-server-for-client-with.html)