# How to connect oracle server via android application?

Tags: android, oracle

I am developing application that connect to the oracle server in my network and i have to fetch data and insert data from my android application.

I know fundamental of web-services but for faster execution i don't want to use web-services. by connecting to my wi-fi i have to access oracle server database. is it possible to doing something like that or any other way any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: You believe that Web services are slow, I think it is slower to implement an Oracle client for android, anyway try with [Oracle Database Mobile](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/products/database-mobile-server/overview/index.html?origref=http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8894665/what-is-the-best-way-to-connect-between-android-and-oracle-database)

Comment: This is my answer you can see it in this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31536756/how-to-connect-android-with-oracle-database

Answer (score 1):

You really don't want to do that directly. Use web-services, they are made for this. Otherwise you need to install an Oracle client on android, which is not available, or fall back to jdbc.

Use web-services, also much more secure and reliable.
Make sure that the web-services you will design do exactly what they should do and process as little as possible on your client. Make sure you make as little round trips as possible. The best way to tune this is not to make a round trip at all.

Comment: but my criteria is to run on any network and for that i have to build different web services for different network