# How to connect Android with Oracle database?

Tags: android, oracle

I am new to android development. I want to develop a android application that update data from a oracle database. Could anyone help me out?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Following post may help you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8894665/what-is-the-best-way-to-connect-between-android-and-oracle-database

Comment: I dont know how to use webservices. I am new to development, have basic knowledge of java. pls help me....

Comment: A web service is the correct answer.  If you can't learn how to do that, then you are not equipped to complete this project.

Answer (score 1):

Use Apache Server to connect android to pc

In php.ini open oci8.dll

in htdocs make php file. 
Your php code is

```
<?PHP

 $con=
"(DESCRIPTION =
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = Your_ip)(PORT = 1521))
(CONNECT_DATA =(SERVER = DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME = Your_db_name)
)
)";
$conn = ocilogon( "User_name", "Password",$con,"WE8ISO8859P15");

$query = "select * from table_name";
        $parseresults = ociparse($conn, $query);

        ociexecute($parseresults);

    while($row=oci_fetch_assoc($parseresults))

 $output[]=$row;

 print json_encode($output);

oci_free_statement($parseresults);
oci_close($conn);

?>
```

In android:

```
public class UploadActivity extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
Context context;

String result;

public UploadActivity(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

@SuppressWarnings("static-access")
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();


}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    final List<Pair<String, String>> postParameters = new ArrayList<>();




        for (int i = 0; i < activity[0].length; i++) {

            //postParameters.add(new Pair<>("var1", activity[i][0]);

            result = null;


            try {

                String response = CustomHttpClient.execute(
                        URL + "Your_php.php", postParameters);
                result = response.toString();
                result = result.replaceAll("(\r\n|\n)", "");

            } catch (Exception e) {

                Log.e("log_tag_ms", "Error in http connection!!" + e.toString());

            }

        }


    return null;
}

protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);


    }  }
```