# Oracle database Connection with Android Studio

Tags: java, android, oracle

I am new to android So can someone tell me how to connect Oracle 10g Express Edition Database to Android in java.. As I am trying to connect it using ojdbc14.jar but it doesn't work for me it gives error. Below mention is a code to make connection with oracle database. So please help me how to solve this issue

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String DEFAULT_DRIVER = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
    private static final String DEFAULT_URL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:8080:apex";
    private static final String DEFAULT_USERNAME = "system";
    private static final String DEFAULT_PASSWORD = "12345";

    private Connection connection;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }

        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hello);
        try {
            this.connection = createConnection();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Connected",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Statement stmt=connection.createStatement();
            StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
            ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from cat");
            while(rs.next()) {
                stringBuffer.append( rs.getString(1)+"\n");
            }
            tv.setText(stringBuffer.toString());
            connection.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ""+e,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static Connection createConnection(String driver, String url, String username, String password) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {

        Class.forName(DEFAULT_DRIVER);
        return DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
    }

    public static Connection createConnection() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        return createConnection(DEFAULT_DRIVER, DEFAULT_URL, DEFAULT_USERNAME, DEFAULT_PASSWORD);
    }



}
```

**Logcat Error:**

```
2021-01-09 12:12:14.391 7420-7420/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.smsapp, PID: 7420
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljava/sql/DriverAction;
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:454)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:379)
        at com.example.smsapp.MainActivity.createConnection(MainActivity.java:61)
        at com.example.smsapp.MainActivity.createConnection(MainActivity.java:66)
        at com.example.smsapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:39)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8000)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "java.sql.DriverAction" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~EJwytfOxILxUukbju8Aaxg==/com.example.smsapp-g50eDPxoOlS69i38LN8oDA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~EJwytfOxILxUukbju8Aaxg==/com.example.smsapp-g50eDPxoOlS69i38LN8oDA==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /system_ext/lib, /product/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:207)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:454) 
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:379) 
        at com.example.smsapp.MainActivity.createConnection(MainActivity.java:61) 
        at com.example.smsapp.MainActivity.createConnection(MainActivity.java:66) 
        at com.example.smsapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:39) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8000) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947) 
2021-01-09 12:12:15.226 7420-7420/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 7420 SIG: 9
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8894819/9701793, This will help you

Comment: I already check that but it is not useful for me..